# Reading a large json file (More then 1 GB) taking unlimited time and RStudio Crashes

Tags: json, r, mongodb, dplyr, rstudio

I have a mongoDB exported json file. Total size of this Json is more then **3GB**.

I am trying to parse nested columns and make my own dataframe for writing in a CSV file.

My code works when the file size is small like 10-20MB. When my file sizes increase it takes unlimited time and at some point RStudio crashes.

I am using **tidyjon** and **dplyr** library to parse json file.

Comment: If it's 3GB, then consider breaking it up. Why are you importing the data from JSON in the first place though? Can you not just directly access the database? Or even import into a local database and connect to that?

Comment: [RMongo on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/index.html)

Comment: R or Rstudio? In any case, if possible, you should interface with the database directly.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I can interface with database, but in similar case how I handle large json files to parse data ? I mean what is the best practice for handle large size of data ?

Comment: @NeilLunn this is client requirement to parse data from json, not from DB.

Comment: Is the issue with reading in the JSON, or manipulating the JSON once you have it in R? The best solution would be to look to use the mongo aggregation framework to do the parsing and formatting on the server, so in R all you do is read the results of the aggregation query.